# Disable google api cache

Tags: caching, google-api-client

just wanted to know is there a way to disable Google API Caching??

In my web App using Google Plus API, it's cacheing terribly huge amount of data causing disc limits being reached, so I have to go and delete the folders by hand.
I found that it's possible to change the directory of cache, but have no idea how to disable it.

Sorry, cannot provide any code samples for this question. Hope it won't be considered inappropriate.

Comment: Try this: https://gist.github.com/lackovic10/4e90e2e8d4c4687c37b7 
the config file (just 1 line): cache_class = "Google_Cache_Null"
I hope this helps, i know it's an old post don't know if this issue is still active. I have been using the google api for android subscriptions so i have no idea about other services, but if i understood you have been using this library https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client Let me know if i can help with anything else.

Comment: config file in a gist: https://gist.github.com/lackovic10/30fe88d16f08245c9a8d

Comment: Currently not working with the API, but will try as soon as have a chance :) Thanks.